# Is there a "canvas_tag" feature for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to use the HTML5 canvas features in a web application. Because there is image_tag and video_tag, I want to know if canvas_tag exist. If so, how do you implement it?

Comment: you can use `content_tag(:canvas) do` block

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is, but there is a [TagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag), which could allow you to create any named tag (like this simplistic example):

```
<%= tag("canvas") %>
```